# Integrating PayU Payment Gateway with Adobe Analytics

Tags: integration, payment-gateway, adobe-analytics, payu, payumoney

I wanted to know if we can integrate PayU money payment gateway with the Adobe analytics. I wanted detailed report which need data not only from PayU but from my own ecommerce website as well.

I have already integrated my website with Adobe analytics, but would need data from payu money to generate customized reports.

Could anyone help me to understand, if something like this is possible?